# Find the number of distinct line ups such that A,B,C are not adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorics-on-words

question:

> 10 peoples including A,B,C are waiting in a line.How many distinct line ups are there such that A,B,C are not adjacent?(assumption: A,B,C may be in any order as long as all three are adjacent)
>   My attempts:

(i) first i put A,B,C in 8 gaps formed by 7 peoples (2 in sides and 6 in between)by $^8C_3$ and arranged rest 7 peoples by $7!$ and got answer as  $^8C_3$$7!=282240$ ways, but answer is coming '3386880'i.e,(10!-8!.3!)

> (i think my answer above is wrong  because i only calculated those cases  where no two peoples are consecutive and left the case where two are consecutive and one is not)

(ii)then,i tried again using $(total-together=not together)$ so, i treated A,B,C as single entity and calculated $(10!-8!=3588480)$(i didn't multiplied 3! to 8! because by assumption given in the question order of A,B,C isn't relevant )

(iii)then, I again tried using formula $(total - together=not together)$
by  calculating total cases as$[10!-3!7!]$ and subtracted cases treating A,B,C as single entity i.e, $8!$  and got answer as $(10!-3!7!-8!)=3558240 $ again got answer wrong

i know i'm doing conceptual mistakes ....please enlighten me.

and  tell how to approach further....thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second approach (ii), you should have multiplied $8!$ by $3!$ so the answer should be $10!-8!\cdot3!$. Actually I don't really understand the assumption you have written since it says "as long as they are adjacent" but we are looking for the cases where all three are not adjacent. But I think it is made in order to emphasize two of them may be adjacent as long as all three are not adjacent. Logically, when you change the places of $A,B$ and $C$ inside when they are adjacent, each permutation of them will give a distinct line therefore the answer should be $10!-8!\cdot3!$.

Comment: by assumption i mean A,BC can never be together like(ABC-------,BCA----------,CAB----------)

Comment: above cases are treated as one

Comment: but these 3 cases will count AB can be together leaving C and similarly 2 others then , why you multiply by 3 factorial as it will also remove cases where AB are together and C not ,BC together and A not,CA together B not

Comment: @ Arsen Berk... and when we are writing 10! it means we are also counting swaps ABC,BCA,CAB, distinct.....how to remove that

Comment: Yes, we have to count swaps as distinct lines so $10!$ is the number of ways of lining (or permuting) $10$ people. Then we subtract the number of linings (or permutations) that $A,B,C$ are adjacent. If we only say $3!$, you are right about what you said but notice that we find $8!$ by sticking $A,B,C$ together and regard them as one person. So we can't seperate $A,B,C$ after we include $8!$ to the calculation.

Comment: @ Arsen berk "when you can't seperate A,B,C after including them" then why multiplying.. 3! to 8!....it meant you are also taking into account the order of A,B,C which shouldn't be taken.....please clear my doubt...Sir

Comment: I understand your doubt but lining the three as $ABC$ and $CAB$ give distinct linings and assumption doesn't mean that you shouldn't consider the linings of $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $3!$ ways for $A,B,C$ to be ordered. Now, given a specific ordering of $A,B,C$ (say, $CAB$), treat this ordering of $A,B,C$ as just $1$ person, and you have $8!$ ways to arrange $7$ people and that specific ordering of $A,B,C$. So the total number of ways that $A,B,C$ can end up adjacent to each other is given by the product of these two: 3!8!. Thus, the number of ways to arrange these people so that $A,B,C$ are not adjacent is $10! - 3!8!$.